# Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes' - React 18.2.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-typescript

I have a question. I am currently learning react with Typescript using the - fullstack react with typescript textbook. I am now on the first app - the trello clone.

I hit a bug I am finding difficult to resolve.

I get this error from the AppStateContext.

`Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'`

This is the block where it is defined: AppStateContext.tsx

```
export const AppStateProvider: FC = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useImmerReducer(appStateReducer, appData)
  const { lists } = state

  const getTasksByListId = (id: string) => {
    return lists.find((list) => list.id === id)?.tasks || []
  }

  return (
    <AppStateContext.Provider value={{ lists, getTasksByListId, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AppStateContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

This is the block where it is called: index.tsx

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
    <AppStateProvider>
      <App />
    </AppStateProvider>
);
```

The error is coming from where I call the  in the index.tsx file.

[image]

I really appreciate the help in advance. React version is 18.2.0

Comment: Try to remove explicit type `FC` from `AppStateProvider`.  Without reproducible example it is hard to say, but you are not allowed to use explicit type `FC` and at the same time type for props. `FC` represents a type of whole component with props. Let me know if it works

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - now that's like magic. I am still learning. Please can you help me understand the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of explicit `FC` type for `AppStateProvider`.

See this simplified example:

```js
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: P, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
}
```

As you might have noticed, `FunctionComponent` is a simplified version (removed props which are not related to your question) of `FC`.

Generic `P` represents `props` argument. If `P` generic don't have `children` property, you are not allowed to use it. In fact you are allowed to use only that properties which are declared in `P` generic.

Please keep in mind, that you have used just `FC`, it means that `P` generic is replaced with `{}`. Hence, you are not allowed to provide any property to react component.

See this:

```js
type Fn<P = 'no properties'> = (props: P) => void

const fn: Fn = (props) => {
    props // no properties
 }
```

`props` has `'no properties'` type, and you are not allowed to override this with another type:

```js
// errpr
const fn: Fn = (props:number) => {
    props // no properties
 }
```

YOur example is a bit different, because typescript type `{}` is a tricky type. Since everything in javascript is object, any (not sure for 100%) type is assignable to `{}`. This is why you don't have an error using `React.PropsWithChildren<{}>` for props. However, using `React.PropsWithChildren<{}>` does not affect `AppStateProvider` type, because when you call it, it will expect only `{}` as a properties.

Just as a rule of thumb, you are allowed to use either explicit type of whole function and avoid using argument type or just use type for argument.

Either this:

```js
type Fn<P = 'no properties'> = (props: P) => void

const fn: Fn = (props) => {
    props // no properties
 }
```

OR

```js
const fn = (props:'no properties') => {
    props // no properties
 }
```

---

P.S. In react 17.*, `FC` had `children type`, see [this](https://tinytip.co/tips/react-vfc/) article

Answer (score 1):

The error is basically telling you that the type of children (which is ELements) has no overlap with your typescript defined type (React.PropsWithChildren<{}>). The easy way to fix the issue is to change the AppStateContext.tsx to something like this:

```
export const AppStateProvider: FC = ({ children }: {children:Elements) => {
...
```

However, if you really want to practice the clean code, and use React.PropsWithChildren, here is a repository with a sample use case:
https://github.com/KishorNaik/Sol_PropsWithChildren_React

HTH